# Deleting a channel using reactions discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I have a little question.
I'm currently in the progress of trying out creating a tickets bot, and had the idea of having so when a user types `!close`, it would present him with an embed, asking him if he really does want to close it using reactions (:wastebasket: for Yes, :x: for No).
If the user reacts for Yes, the channel will close. As for No, the embed message will be deleted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will be glad to help.

You can use something a little like this:

```
const prevMsg = message
message.channel.send(embed).then(message => {
  const questionMessage = message;
  questionMessage.react('️')
  .then(() => questionMessage.react('❌'));
  const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return ['️', '❌'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === prevMsg.author.id;
};

  questionMessage.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first();

        if (reaction.emoji.name === '️') {
            // closing function here
        } else {
            questionMessage.delete();
        }
    })
})
```

If it didn't work, please let me know!

Comment: Hi there, first off all, thank you so much for helping me!

Unfortunately, while the message itself is working and is being reacted to, reacting to the messages doesn't seem to do anything.
Is there something I need to edit that I missed?

Comment: Is there anything in the console?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it, no.
Would you like me to send you the full code through Discord?

Comment: I think I have a solution. Unfortunately, I have to leave the house for an hour or two. I will let you know when I’m back.

Comment: No rush whatsoever!
I appreciate your help so much my man :3

Comment: One thing I'd like to note, is that the "unknown reaction" command works by itself, although this also occurs when you react with :wastebucket: or :x:..

Comment: Hi again!
It doesn't appear to work just yet.
Right now, it seems like the bot is replying to its own reaction (that I, unfortunately, haven't really gotten to learn how to prevent yet), and nothing really happens when I react to it myself.

Comment: I have provided another updated snippet. Does this work?

Comment: Hi, again IceBot! The :x: reaction works very well! It removed the message as it should but there are just 2 remaining problems. 1 being the channel not getting deleted, perhaps this is something on my end as I'm the one who set it to this. The second being that it seems like whenever I run the command it comes up with the Embed, as well as the error of the emoji not being one of the two, even though I haven't reacted yet. Would you mind if I message you the full code on discord? Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi! I left it up to you on how to close the channel. The code has been updated, yet again. You can remove where it says `// closing function here` and put your closing function there. I've removed the `.catch(collected)` part. I hope this helps!

Comment: I got it to work, thank you so much for your patience with me my guy, I really do appreciate it <3

Comment: Hey! No problem! Can't wait to see you later :D